# Ruby strftime '%Z' method returns '0545' instead of 'NPT'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

After upgrading my MacOS to latest version, I am having some weird issue with the Time#strftime method.

```
Time.now.in_time_zone("Kathmandu").strftime("%Z") #=> '+0545'
Time.now.in_time_zone("Bangkok").strftime("%Z") #=> '+07'
Time.now.in_time_zone("Nairobi").strftime("%Z") #=> 'EAT'
Time.now.in_time_zone("New Delhi").strftime("%Z") #=> 'IST'
```

My current ruby version is:

```
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

I have tried it on:

```
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

and still not working

I tried this on my friend's machine (ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin15]) and its working fine.

```
Time.now.in_time_zone("Kathmandu").strftime("%Z") #=> 'NPT'
Time.now.in_time_zone("Bangkok").strftime("%Z") #=> 'ICT'
Time.now.in_time_zone("Nairobi").strftime("%Z") #=> 'EAT'
Time.now.in_time_zone("New Delhi").strftime("%Z") #=> 'IST'
```

Comment: `%Z `is highly dependent on the operating system. `%z`, is recommended for the numeric time zone offset.

Comment: What is your question? This looks like bug report rather than a question. You seem to have posted on a wrong web site.

Comment: Thank you for your response. %z returns offset value from UTC. Is there any better way to get the abbreviated name for the timezone? @孙悟空

Answer (score 4):

The time zone methods in ruby depend solely on the **[IANA tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html)** that is installed in the OS. The difference that you observe between your computer and your friend's computer simply reflects the fact that you had your tz database upgraded to a newer version along with the OS upgrade.

And, indeed, there is an **ongoing effort of IANA to remove some of the time zone abbreviations**. They are removing those abbreviations that are considered "invented", i.e. named centrally by the IANA crew and not corresponding to any real-world usage in the appropriate localities. See also the following [official IANA statement](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html#notation):

> Alphabetic time zone abbreviations should not be used as unique identifiers for UTC offsets as they are ambiguous in practice. For example, in English-speaking North America "CST" denotes 6 hours behind UTC, but in China it denotes 8 hours ahead of UTC, and French-speaking North Americans prefer "HNC" to "CST". The tz database contains English abbreviations for many time stamps; **unfortunately some of these abbreviations were merely the database maintainers' inventions, and are gradually being removed**.

For example, the abbreviation for Kathmandu has been specifically removed in January 2017, with [this commit](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/1b99dcde6342dd10969041b32b00b813d4f4a36e).

So, I guess you should stick to the output that `strftime` gives you, and actually use the numeric value for some time zones.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a converter who transfer the numeric time zone offset to the abbreviated name. define a hash constant like

```
{
... 
'+0200' => 'CEST',
'+0530' => 'IST',
...
}
```

[List complet](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)